# No description of theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am trying to create a child theme. I can't find the description for the parent theme anywhere so I added the title of the parent theme in the Template and it gives me the following error.

"VTube-child    The parent theme is missing. Please install the "VTube" parent theme."

It is a theme developed by WP-scripts. Their customer support sucks, so is their anyway else I can find the description of the theme.

Comment: in order for a child theme to be recognized by wp, you need to ceate a `style.css` file with header comments, this particular line instructs wordpress telling it the parent's theme name: `Template:     parent-theme-name` https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/

Comment: Yeah, I know. The problem is that the theme title is VTube but it is not recognized, which means it has a different name. Is there some file where the name and the details, i.e, the description of the theme is preserved.  I can't find it in by going to Dashboard/Themes, the description portion is empty.

Comment: Never mind. It works now after I wrote the parent theme name in small letter.